# php Get all values from multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

how can i get all values from multidimensional associative array
I dont want to use print_r want to control my array put all the value in normal array with unique values
 my array is look like this

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string 'DEMO' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string 'Home_Sec' (length=8)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  2 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string 'Back_Brace' (length=10)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string 'Home_Sec' (length=8)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string '' (length=0)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string 'home_Sec_2' (length=10)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'Campaign' => string 'Burial_Ins' (length=10)
  7 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  8 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  9 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

I dont want to use print_r want to control my array put all the value in normal array with unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$array = array(...); //your values here
function output($item, $key) {
     echo $key . ' =>' . $item;
}
array_walk($array, 'output');
```

Comment: its give me this  value       0 =>Array1 =>Array2 =>Array3 =>Array4 =>Array5 =>Array6 =>Array7 =>Array8 =>Array9 =>Array

Comment: thanks for the clue your code is good but in my case need to use array_walk_recursive  thanks any way

Answer (score 2):

`array_walk` is an option, but here's another option if you want to try something a bit more coded by yourself, solving this problem **recursively**

This will flatten **any** n-max level array into a single array that contains all the values of all the sub arrays (including the initial array itself)

```
<?php
$array = array(
1 => array(1, 2, 3, 4 => array(
1, 2, 3, 4
)),
4, 5);
function recurse_values($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $output_array = array();
        foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
            $primitive_output = recurse_values($val);
            if (is_array($primitive_output)) {
                $output_array = array_merge($output_array, $primitive_output);
            }
            else {
                array_push($output_array, $primitive_output);
            }
        }
        return $output_array;
    }
    else {
        return $array;
    }
}
print_r(recurse_values($array));
?>
```

If you need unique values, at the end you can add a [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to do this.

Comment: thanks but the solution by @Machavity suites me more

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you can "flatten" this multi-dimensional array into a one dimension? Possible solutions to similar problems... [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: yes that will be one of the solution can tell me how

Comment: Edited with link to a similar problem. I personally like the second solution by "too much php"